# bookshelf.js retrieve model name & assign it to instance via virtuals-plugin #beginner

Tags: bookshelf.js

I feel like this is a very stupid question, but as much as I try, I don't get any closer to solving it on my own;

So, here we go:

I install & setup the virtual plugin:

```
bookshelf.plugin('bookshelf-virtuals-plugin');
```

and then comes defining the getter:

```
...bookshelf.model(
  'MasterModel',
  {
    virtuals: {
      type() { return this.constructor.name; }
    }
  ...
  });
...
```

Later on, I extend this master model and define other models. The hope is to be able to retrieve the name of the last model in the chain that the current variable is an instance of via something like: `instance.get('type')`.

I presumed there must be an attribute/method on bookshelf's `Model` object to access that one defines during definition, but no luck finding one in the api documentation!

PS. I'm using the virtual because I wish to skip moderating serialization mechanism of `toJSON()`.

Comment: So, what you want is to determine if some model is of a certain type? For example, if you have a `Customer` model that inherits from `MasterModel` you want to know if some model is an instance of `Customer`?

Comment: Yes, at the moment I'm just trying to avoid repeating myself by adding an additional method to every model definition like `kind: function() { return 'ModelName';}`. However, I think such feature is important for programatic approaches to initiating, calling & etc.

Comment: That's already possible, but you're thinking about it backwards. I'll add a reply explaining how you can achieve what you want.

Answer (score 0):

If all you want is to determine if a model is of a certain type you just need this:

```
const MyModel = bookshelf.model('MyModel')

// next some place where you need to check the model type
if (anotherModel instanceof MyModel) {
  // do stuff
}
```

Comment: Thanks! But that's a funny workaround of the question. I'm retrieving data & passing them via api, so on the other side the JSON entries are not marked with anything to check what the model it is. In Ruby & PHP ORM's I'm using, I usually define a virtual attribute that returns the `class.name` or `class.type()` or something like that (`this.name` from inside a static attribute on the model).

Comment: That wasn't part of the question, so I can only answer based on what is there. If you really need to set something in the JSON output you are better off overriding the `serialize` method instead of virtuals that were never designed to do that: https://bookshelfjs.org/api.html#Model-instance-serialize

Comment: I guessed it too, I just used victuals as a quick fix, because I couldn't fathom what to write int he serialize. I was trying to understand how to get the name with which a model is registered in Bookshelf from a (static) function on the model. Thanks for advices, anyway.

Comment: here is another use case: https://github.com/bookshelf/bookshelf/issues/2073#issuecomment-626263738